# lmer with random effects shows insignificant interaction term despite confidence intervals not overlapping

Tags: r, lm, lme4-nlme, confidence-interval

I am trying to interpret an analysis on urchin biomass and how the means differ between 2 sites (Waikiki and Hanauma Bay) and 2 experimental treatments (low and high shelter).  Because of the nature of my study, I have sampled experimental units ("Module #") repeatedly through time.  As such I used a random effect term to account for repeated measures and psuedoreplication.

Because my data are highly positively skewed, I decided to transform the data using a quarter root transformation.  I then ran an analysis on those transformed data and found the site and shelter terms to be significant but not their interaction.  When you look at the means and confidence intervals plotted in the barplot, you can see that there is a large difference between the Hanauma Bay low and high shelter treatments.  However, the interaction term is not significant which makes me question how to interpret this.

When I ran an lm without a random effect or did not transform the data, the interaction term came out significant in the analysis.  Does anyone have any sense of how to interpret these results and if I should either use an lm or not transform the data for this analysis?  The barplot below represents the untransformed data to be clear.  Thanks in advance!

#### Barplot with urchin biomass means and 95% CI

[image]

#### Transformed Analysis

[image]

```
> urchin_lmer <- lmer(urchin_biomass_trans ~ Site_long*Shelter + (1|module_urchins), data = mean_urchin_totals2, na.action = "na.fail")
> summary(urchin_lmer)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: urchin_biomass_trans ~ Site_long * Shelter + (1 | module_urchins)
   Data: mean_urchin_totals2

REML criterion at convergence: 470.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.4308 -0.5978 -0.2350  0.5821  3.2883 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 module_urchins (Intercept) 0.4449   0.667   
 Residual                   1.8899   1.375   
Number of obs: 132, groups:  module_urchins, 12

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  2.7707     0.3211  8.9334   8.630 1.26e-05 ***
Site_longWaikiki            -2.1808     0.4544  8.9472  -4.799 0.000991 ***
Shelter.L                    1.0569     0.4005 18.3559   2.639 0.016491 *  
Site_longWaikiki:Shelter.L  -0.6752     0.5524 21.2600  -1.222 0.235015    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) St_lnW Shlt.L
Site_lngWkk -0.707              
Shelter.L   -0.053  0.038       
St_lngW:S.L  0.039  0.010 -0.725
```

[image]

#### Untransformed Data

[image]

```
> urchin_lmer <- lmer(urchin_biomass ~ Site_long*Shelter + (1|module_urchins), data = mean_urchin_totals2, na.action = "na.fail")
> summary(urchin_lmer)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: urchin_biomass ~ Site_long * Shelter + (1 | module_urchins)
   Data: mean_urchin_totals2

REML criterion at convergence: 1782.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6712 -0.3379 -0.0837  0.0164  4.0181 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 module_urchins (Intercept)  1757     41.92  
 Residual                   56857    238.45  
Number of obs: 132, groups:  module_urchins, 12

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 235.901     34.037    8.329   6.931 9.95e-05 ***
Site_longWaikiki           -202.920     48.187    8.339  -4.211  0.00269 ** 
Shelter.L                   181.045     47.258   11.304   3.831  0.00266 ** 
Site_longWaikiki:Shelter.L -148.160     66.607   12.243  -2.224  0.04566 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) St_lnW Shlt.L
Site_lngWkk -0.706              
Shelter.L   -0.060  0.042       
St_lngW:S.L  0.042  0.014 -0.710
```

[image]

#### lm with transformed data (without random effects)

```
urchin_lm <- lm(urchin_biomass_trans ~ Site_long*Shelter, data = mean_urchin_totals2, na.action = "na.fail")
summary(urchin_lm)

Call:
lm(formula = urchin_biomass_trans ~ Site_long * Shelter, data = mean_urchin_totals2, 
    na.action = "na.fail")

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5929 -0.7988 -0.3708  1.1944  4.7548 

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  2.7658     0.1837  15.057  < 2e-16 ***
Site_longWaikiki            -2.1810     0.2601  -8.386 7.86e-14 ***
Shelter.L                    1.1696     0.2598   4.502 1.49e-05 ***
Site_longWaikiki:Shelter.L  -0.8670     0.3678  -2.357   0.0199 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.49 on 128 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.431, Adjusted R-squared:  0.4177 
F-statistic: 32.32 on 3 and 128 DF,  p-value: 1.277e-15
```

Comment: I had used a log transformation initially but found that a quarter root transformation normalized the distribution best.  Can you clarify your second question?  Corals are growting on 12 modules (6 at Waikiki and 6 at Hanuama Bay).

Comment: and are there 3 modules within each shelter type in each site?

Comment: That's correct.  The experimental design is 3 high shelter and 3 low shelter modules at both Waikiki and Hanauma Bay.

Comment: then you would almost certainly be better off (in terms of simplicity and correctness) averaging the values for each module, transforming as appropriate, and then using `lm()` on the resulting 12 data points.

Comment: Do you happen to know if that would drasticallly reduce the statistical power of my analyses?

Comment: Or is that actually about the same as what I am doing now?

Comment: And to follow up, I am doing these same analyses with coral demography in which corals are growing on these structures.  There are over a hundred corals on each module.  Do you think that because say I am working with maybe 10 corals from each module (120 corals) but with many being on the same module, wouldn't I need to use a random effect to account for the fact that the corals are not only being sampled multiple times but share the same experimental unit with other corals?

Comment: read the Murtaugh paper: for *nested* designs like yours, the power should be identical

Comment: Thank you very much for that citation!  Another point that I was looking into was how much the standard deviation and variance of the random effect term.  Since in my case the standard deviation is less than 1, is that also a potential indicator in your opinion that the random effect term should be dropped instead of included?

Comment: No..............

Comment: Excuse my hesitancy to ditch random effect terms.  In my R training, I have had random effects emphasized as a way to account for repeated measures through time (which definitely applies in this case).  I am not a statistician obviously and as such I rely on the expert opinions of others along with references.  After reading through Murtaugh, I still do not understand how I can get around using random effects terms when measures of  urchins and corals on the experimental unit (module) was done for these analyses 10 times.  These data are a time series